# Creating User Control works with AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a user control with 3 images: like, dislike and comment buttons. I want to like and dislike button to save some info to the database (liked user and liked object). But i want to work them without reloading the page.

Example scenario:

- Like button shows like count if the post has any
- User likes a blog post.
- Save like process to the DB
- Disable like button.

I want to implement this operation via AJAX call to the page in which the control is used, inside of the control. I don't want to implement them separately. When another developer wanted to use this, he/she must use the control just by instantiating. Also, it must be used more than once in a page.

Regards.

Comment: I already read some documents about AJAX server control, but it looked like a little bit complicated for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your buttons inside an update panel in the user control.

This [Introduction to the UpdatePanels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) will get you started.

Then other developers can use you control on any other page without any trouble.

Update panels are server controls that internally make ajax calls and update their contents.
Should work perfectly for what you want.

Comment: I think update panels are very exprensive to use. This control will be used in page maybe 10 times.

Comment: No, they will not be expensive, the js required for any server control, is loaded only once even if you use it 10 times. Also these scripts are cached at the client side. So until you change your build, most clients won't download them again. Since they are so simple to add and remove, why don't you try and benchmark the performance.

Comment: Ok i've been trying your suggestion, so far so good. Thanks for help.